# Conditional validation with react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-forms

Here is my form looks like and also [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-conditional-fields-forked-mj7sl?file=/src/index.css). currently I'm using react-hook-form 
as you can see form has 3 inputs. Submit button should be disabled until all the required fields are entered.
Two use case:

1. If "Check" is unchecked:

   - only "id" should be validated and submit button should get enabled. "firt" and "last" names should not be part of form data
2. If "Check" is checked

   - all the fields should be validated
     first and last names are only required if "Check" is checked. so its not checked then form should only validate "ID" field. if "Check" is checked then all fields should get validated.

problem I'm having is if I enter id, form state is still "invalid". Form is expecting to enter values for first and last name.
I would appreciate any help.

[image: Form]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have updated your CodeSanBox code and also adding the full code here:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./index.css";

function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    errors,
    formState,
    unregister,
    setValue,
    getValues,
    reset
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    reValidateMode: "onBlur",
    shouldUnregister: true
  });
  //console.log(formState.isValid);
  console.log(errors);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    // @ts-ignore

    if (disabled) {
      console.log("unregister");
      reset({ ...getValues(), firstName: undefined, lastName: undefined });
      unregister(["firstName", "lastName"]);
    } else {
      console.log("register");
      register("firstName", { required: true });
      register("lastName", { required: true });
    }
  }, [disabled]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label htmlFor="id">ID</label>
      <input
        name="id"
        placeholder="id"
        ref={register({ required: true, maxLength: 50 })}
      />
      {errors.id && <p>"ID is required"</p>}
      <fieldset disabled={disabled}>
        <legend>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={"name"}
            ref={register}
            onClick={() => setDisabled(!disabled)}
          />
          <span>Check</span>
        </legend>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="Bill"
          onChange={(e) => {
            console.log(e.target.value);
            setValue("firstName", e.target.value);
          }}
          ref={register({ required: !disabled })}
        />
        {errors.firstName && <p>"First name is required"</p>}
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input
          name="lastName"
          placeholder="Luo"
          onChange={(e) => setValue("lastName", e.target.value)}
          ref={register({ required: !disabled })}
        />
        {errors.lastName && <p>"Last name is required"</p>}
      </fieldset>

      <input type="submit" disabled={!formState.isValid} />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

First I found that you set `disabled` state as `false` which should be `true` as an initial value, and regarding the issue, I have used `reset` and `getValues` functions when the `disabled` state changes.

**EDIT** for you to recognize code changes easy, I have restored all the code at CodeSanBox.

Comment: How to do the same when using resolver like Joi or Yup for validation, Is there any way to dynamically change resolver validation depending upon conditions ?

Comment: @NabeelHussainShah Check out the [when](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema) clause if you are using Yup

Comment: @callmekatootie need to give u a medal, when is what I need man, thank youuuuu

Answer (score 6):

This whole validation behavior (UX) is definitely making things a bit harder, however, there are a couple of things that you should leverage from the library such as:

- `watch`
- `validate`
- `getValues`

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

import "./index.css";

function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    errors,
    formState: { isValid, touched },
    getValues,
    trigger,
    watch
  } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur"
  });
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };
  const validate = (value) => {
    if (getValues("name")) { // read the checkbox value
      return !!value;
    }

    return true;
  };
  const isChecked = watch("name"); // watch if the name is checked

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <label htmlFor="id">ID</label>
      <input
        name="id"
        placeholder="id"
        ref={register({ required: true, maxLength: 50 })}
      />
      {errors.id && <p>"ID is required"</p>}

      <fieldset disabled={!isChecked}>
        <legend>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name={"name"}
            ref={register}
            onChange={() => trigger()} // you want update isValid due to state change, and also those extra two inputs become required
          />
          <span>Check</span>
        </legend>
        <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input
          name="firstName"
          placeholder="Bill"
          ref={register({
            validate
          })}
        />
        // make sure input is touched before fire an error message to the user
        {errors.firstName && touched["firstName"] && (
          <p>"First name is required"</p>
        )}
        <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input
          name="lastName"
          placeholder="Luo"
          ref={register({
            validate
          })}
        />
        {errors.lastName && touched["lastName"] && (
          <p>"Last name is required"</p>
        )}
      </fieldset>

      <input type="submit" disabled={!isValid} />
    </form>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

CSB:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-conditional-fields-forked-n0jig?file=/src/index.js:0-1831

Answer (score 1):

on your ref, dont use hard coded bool `true`, `ref={register({ required: true})}`, but your dynamic `ref={register({ required: disabled })}`

do notice that because your `mode: "onBlur"` config, the button won't be abled until `id` field blurred

Comment: thx @hagai , i modified my code as per your suggestion, it is still not behaving as desire. also, mode:'onblur" is intentional to have formState.isValid , "formState.isValid" is not applicable in case of mode:"onSubmit"

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace true .from ref: required:true..... Instead use const 'disabled' ....in input of first and last name .

So as to achieve dynamic change

Comment: thx @nihal , i modified my code as per your suggestion, it is still not behaving as desire. also, mode:'onblur" is intentional to have formState.isValid , "formState.isValid" is not applicable in case of mode:"onSubmit"

Answer (score 1):

Same problem. That's what I came up with.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-b557bc?file=App.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import { useForm, useWatch, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    unregister,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      isOnline: true,
      isRegular: false,
      urlAddress: '',
      cityAddress: '',
      startDate: '',
    },
  });

  const [isOnline, isRegular] = useWatch({
    control,
    name: ['isOnline', 'isRegular'],
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log('data: ', data);
  console.log('errors: ', errors);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isOnline) {
      register('urlAddress');
      unregister('cityAddress');
    } else {
      register('cityAddress');
      unregister('urlAddress');
    }
  }, [register, unregister, isOnline]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isRegular) {
      register('startDate');
    } else {
      unregister('startDate');
    }
  }, [register, unregister, isRegular]);

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="isOnline"
        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            checked={value}
            value={value}
            onChange={onChange}
          />
        )}
      />

      {isOnline ? (
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="urlAddress"
          rules={{ required: { value: true, message: 'urlAddress required' } }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
            <div>
              <div>urlAddress</div>
              <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
              error: {error?.message}
            </div>
          )}
        />
      ) : (
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="cityAddress"
          rules={{ required: { value: true, message: 'cityAddress required' } }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
            <div>
              <div>cityAddress</div>
              <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
              error: {error?.message}
            </div>
          )}
        />
      )}

      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="isRegular"
        render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
          <input type="checkbox" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
        )}
      />

      {isRegular && (
        <Controller
          control={control}
          name="startDate"
          rules={{ required: { value: true, message: 'startDate required' } }}
          render={({ field: { onChange, value }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
            <div>
              <div>startDate</div>
              <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
              error: {error?.message}
            </div>
          )}
        />
      )}

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```